# What is spatie/laravel-backup password and how to overwrite It?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backup

When I do a backup, we transfer It to another server and today I wanted to unzip to check the contents and It asks me for a password.

I checked the config files, documentation, but I cannot seem to find where to find It or how to set It

Package: spatie/laravel-backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the config of spatie/laravel-backup is the following entry:

```
    /*
     * The password to be used for archive encryption.
     * Set to `null` to disable encryption.
     */
    'password' => env('BACKUP_ARCHIVE_PASSWORD'),
```

So either is here a password set or have a look to your .env file and search for `BACKUP_ARCHIVE_PASSWORD`.

Comment: I am on spatie backup v6

Comment: Have you checked your .env file?

Another way to check your password is by starting `php artisan tinker` and then execute `config('backup.backup.password');`

Comment: I have It as null. Even if It set the BACKUP_ARCHIVE_PASSWORD and try to unpack It with 7z x (backup name) i get prompted to add the password and it always fails

Comment: Okay, that sounds strange. Before this feature was introduced, there was an suggestion to manipulate the zip archive by listening to the `BackupZipWasCreated` event, perhaps you have some event here in your project?

Comment: Yes, you were correct. I had an Event listener that was overwriting how the backup is encrypted. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

As @stefket suggested, we had a BackupZipWasCreated event listener that was overwriting how backups are encrypted.

Kudos to @stefket!